# Do we lose much if we take isomorphism as equality in a purely algebraic context?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In algebra, we sometimes end up with a sentence relating two objets via an isomorphism. As algebra is kind of spiritual behavior of objects, (we almost never speak about the object, but we speak about the equivalence class (isomorphism) of objects that satisties a certain hypotesis) and isomorphism is often enough to say stuff about objects, I wonder if we really lose much information if we take "isomorphic" objects as "equal" objects in a pure algebraic setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only studying a single object then it shouldn't be a problem to only do it up to isomorphism in most algebraic cases.

You have to be careful when multiple isomorphic objects are present. For example, let $V$ be a two-dimensional vector space with basis $b_1,b_2$. Set $U_1 = \langle b_1 \rangle$ and $U_2 = \langle b_2 \rangle$. Then $V = U_1 + U_2$ and $U_1$ and $U_2$ are isomorphic, but they are not equal, as otherwise we would have $V = U_1 = U_2$.

This example might seem constructed (because, of course, it is), but such cases can happen as soon as there are multiple (sub)objects present.